# WPF: Data binding with ListView get error: "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource"

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to set my ListView databinding to ObservableCollection. And I add context menu with checking permission for each item in list view. So I get an error: "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource". But if I remove ItemsSource in ListView, I can't use databinding.
Can you help me? You can download example at http://www.mediafire.com/?r21lm8ud9q92o5k

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}"
        Height="259" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,26,0,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479">
        <ListView.Items>                
            <ListViewItem>                    
                <ListViewItem.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Kiểm tra">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="Images/CompareFiles.png" Style="{StaticResource ImageContextMenu}"/>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>

                        <MenuItem Header="Download" Visibility="{Binding Path=Name, Converter={StaticResource MenuContext}, ConverterParameter= {x:Static ObservableCollectionProblem:EnumUserAction.Download}}">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="Images/SyncCurrentObject.png" Style="{StaticResource ImageContextMenu}"/>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="Upload" Visibility="{Binding Path=Actions, Converter={StaticResource MenuContext}, ConverterParameter = {x:Static ObservableCollectionProblem:EnumUserAction.Upload}}">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="Images/upload.png" Style="{StaticResource ImageContextMenu}"/>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ListViewItem.ContextMenu>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Actions, Converter={StaticResource ActionToStringConverter}}" Header="Action"></GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListViewItem>
        </ListView.Items>
        <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Kiểm tra">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/CompareFiles.png" Style="{StaticResource ImageContextMenu}"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>

                <MenuItem Header="Download" Visibility="{Binding Path=Name, Converter={StaticResource MenuContext}, ConverterParameter= {x:Static ObservableCollectionProblem:EnumUserAction.Download}}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/SyncCurrentObject.png" Style="{StaticResource ImageContextMenu}"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Upload" Visibility="{Binding Path=Actions, Converter={StaticResource MenuContext}, ConverterParameter = {x:Static ObservableCollectionProblem:EnumUserAction.Upload}}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/upload.png" Style="{StaticResource ImageContextMenu}"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>                    
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>                    
                <GridViewColumn Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Actions, Converter={StaticResource ActionToStringConverter}}" Header="Action"></GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only have once source for the items in a `ListView`, in this case it looks like you are explicitly setting the `ListView.Items` collection in XAML. This would cause the error you are seeing when it tries to bind using ItemsSource.

Maybe try removing the `ListView.Items` node from your XAML and only use the `ItemsSource` binding to populate the list.

It looks like you would also want to use the `ListView.ItemTemplate` to format the items how you want and get the context menus right.

Comment: You can example. I want to design two column and it appears like ListView and it has context menu for each item.

Comment: I can set context menu in GridViewColumn.CellTemplate, but I think it's stupid if I have many columns, I repeat it many times.

Comment: I'd prefer not to write it for you, there are lots of examples for using data templates with ListView: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx or http://www.wpftutorial.net/datatemplates.html

Comment: That's true, you might be able to use CellTemplate to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I add context menu in ItemContainerStyle and its success

```
<ListView Height="259" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,26,0,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479">                         
        <ListView.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu">                    
                <MenuItem Header="Kiểm tra">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/CompareFiles.png" Style="{StaticResource ImageContextMenu}"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Download" Visibility="{Binding Path=Actions, Converter={StaticResource MenuContext}, ConverterParameter= {x:Static ObservableCollectionProblem:EnumUserAction.Download}}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/SyncCurrentObject.png" Style="{StaticResource ImageContextMenu}"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Upload" Visibility="{Binding Path=Actions, Converter={StaticResource MenuContext}, ConverterParameter = {x:Static ObservableCollectionProblem:EnumUserAction.Upload}}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/upload.png" Style="{StaticResource ImageContextMenu}"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="OnListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ItemContextMenu}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>                
            <GridView>                    
                <GridViewColumn Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Actions, Converter={StaticResource ActionToStringConverter}}" Header="Action"></GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```